# In gRPC, can the receiver of a unidirectional stream to cancel the stream and send an error to the sender?

Tags: grpc, grpc-go

In a gRPC unidirectional client-to-server stream, it is possible for the server to cancel the stream and return an error message to the client?

I've tried setting a trailer and returning a status message with `.SendAndClose()`, but neither are readable from the client. At the client, `.Send` returns an `EOF` error as expected, but `.CloseAndRecv()` does not return the status message sent by the server and `.Trailer()` returns an empty map.

// protobuf:

```protobuf
service Foo {
    rpc Eat (stream Food) returns (Status) {}
}
```

// Server:

```golang
var Retval pb.Status
Retval.Status = "something went wrong"

emap := make(map[string]string)
emap["error"] = "something went wrong"
MD := metadata.New(emap)

Stream.SetTrailer(MD)
Stream.SendAndClose(&Retval)
```

// Client:

```golang
err = Stream.Send(Stuff) // returns EOF
if err != nil {
    Status, err := o.Stream.CloseAndRecv() //returns nil, EOF
    
    MD := o.Stream.Trailer() // returns an empty map.
}
```

Is there a way to do this without a bidirectional stream or a separate RPC endpoint for the client to request status messages from the server?

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to define the Status object in your proto file. You can for example return a Well Known Type called Empty.

To do this you can do:

```
import "google/protobuf/empty.proto"

service Foo {
    rpc Eat (stream Food) returns (google.protobuf.Empty);
}
```

This is just a recommendation because you don't need to provide a Status object. gRPC already has one defined that you can use in your go code.

Then on the server side you don't need to call `SendAndClose` when you want to return an error because your `Eat` function will have the following function declaration:

```golang
func (*Server) Eat(stream pb.Foo_EatServer) error
```

You can use something like the following code to send a status specifying that you had an error.

```golang
return nil, status.Errorf(
    codes.Internal, // check suitable code
    "A description for the error",
)
```

and before returning you can set a Trailer that will trigger error on the client side.

On the client side, you'll need to do something like:

```golang
trailer := stream.Trailer()
v, exist := trailer["error"]
if exist { // there is an error
    fmt.Println("Error: ", v)
}
```

let me know if you need more help on that.

Comment: As I said in my question, my problem is that `Stream.Trailer()` returns an empty map. I didn't include any code to read from the map as it was not relevant.

Comment: @user3518060 I updated, let me know if you need more details. And please give us more code so that we can better reproduce the problem